# Add an item in list view from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, addition

I am new in android development and i found a hard time in programming this is why i am asking for your help. I am working on project that i can add notes on a list. I have also an activity that i edit the note and i want there to add a button that when i click on it, to add an item in front of my note in noteActivity. I have in my mind to add an explanation mark infront of the note to be marked as an important one. I really dont know how to do that and i am crying. Please could anyone help me with that? is there a any example of how can i do that?

Here is my main activity that the notes are apeared:

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private static final int EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST = 1001;
private NotesDataSource datasource;
List<NoteItem> notesList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    datasource = new NotesDataSource(this);

    refreshDisplay();

}

private void refreshDisplay() {
    notesList= datasource.findAll();
    ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, notesList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_create) {
     createNote();  
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void createNote() {

    NoteItem note = NoteItem.getNew();
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());
 intent.putExtra("text", note.getText());
 startActivityForResult(intent, EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    NoteItem note = notesList.get(position);
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());
     intent.putExtra("text", note.getText());
     startActivityForResult(intent, EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        NoteItem note = new NoteItem();
        note.setKey(data.getStringExtra("key"));
        note.setText(data.getStringExtra("text"));
        datasource.update(note);
        refreshDisplay();
    }
}
 }
```

And this is my NoteEditorActivity

```
    public class NoteEditorActivity extends Activity{

private NoteItem note;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Intent intent = this.getIntent(); 
note = new NoteItem();
note.setKey(intent.getStringExtra("key"));
note.setText(intent.getStringExtra("text"));

EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.headerText);
et.setText(note.getText());
et.setSelection(note.getText().length());
}

private void saveAndFinish(){
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.headerText);
    String headerText = et.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());
     intent.putExtra("text", headerText);
     setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
     finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()== android.R.id.home) {
        saveAndFinish();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    saveAndFinish();
}

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

read the section to ArrayAdapter.

For the solution you have to add the marked information to your NoteItem class and the check the getters in the adapter as well (add them to your class)

You need to write your own custom adapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final int EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST = 1001;
private NotesDataSource datasource;
List<NoteItem> notesList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    datasource = new NotesDataSource(this);

    refreshDisplay();

}

private void refreshDisplay() {
    notesList= datasource.findAll();
    ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> adapter =
            new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_layout, notesList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_create) {
     createNote();  
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void createNote() {

    NoteItem note = NoteItem.getNew();
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());
 intent.putExtra("text", note.getText());
 startActivityForResult(intent, EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    NoteItem note = notesList.get(position);
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());
     intent.putExtra("text", note.getText());
     startActivityForResult(intent, EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        NoteItem note = new NoteItem();
        note.setKey(data.getStringExtra("key"));
        note.setText(data.getStringExtra("text"));
        datasource.update(note);
        refreshDisplay();
    }
}

private class CustomAdapter extend ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> {

    private int mResourceId;
    private List<NoteItem> mData;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<NoteItem> data) {
       super(context, resourceId, data);
       mResourceId = resourceId;
       mData = data;
    }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        NoteItem item = mData.get(position);        

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(resourceId, null);  
        }

        TextView titleTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView textTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        CheckBox markedCB = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mark);

        titleTV.setText(item.getKey());
        textTV.setText(item.getText());
        markedCB.setChecked(itemt.getMarked());

        return convertView;         
     }
}
 }
```

Save the following as custom_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


     <CheckBox
       android:id="@+id/mark"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/title"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You create always a new adapter, that's not a good method. Use instead clear() and add():
[Docu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29)